# Question about faceapi.detectAllFaces return

Tags: javascript, face-api

I'm using faceapi.detectAllFaces.

I need to know if, indeed, a face was detected or if the video was without any face.

When I return the content of faceapi.detectAllFaces, it only returns {objectct Object].

But I just need to know if a face was detected or not.

How can I access this return?

Comment: Please use JSON.Stringfy method for see detail

Answer (score 0):

```
const faces = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(...
if (!faces.length) {
//...
}
```